# Remove falsy values, but not 0, from object

Tags: javascript, filter

Is there a nicer way (for example with `filter`) to remove values from **object** than this?

```
const filters = {
   a: null,
   b: 0,
   c: 'xxx',
   d: 'abc',
}

const MY_FALSY = [undefined, '', null];
const newFilters = Object.entries(filters).reduce(
  (a, [k, v]) =>
    MY_FALSY.indexOf(v) > -1 ? a : { ...a, [k]: v },
  {}
);
```

Is there a better way to do it? I tried to use filter but I had to use `delete` which as I know we should avoid.

NOTE: I don't want to use any libraries like underscore.js

Outcome:

```
{
   b: 0,
   c: 'xxx',
   d: 'abc',
}
```

Comment: Object.keys(obj).forEach(key=>  obj[key] || obj[key]===0 ? obj[key] : delete obj[key])

This code above will remove falsy valued keys from the object. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work for me

Comment: I don't want array of values I want to keep it as object of filters

Comment: I added an answer, where you pass your filter to the function and it returns another object which do not contain and falsy value.

Answer (score 1):

```
const removeFalsy = (myObject)=>{
  const new_obj = {...myObject};
  Object.keys(new_obj).forEach(key=> new_obj[key] || new_obj[key]===0 ? new_obj[key] : delete new_obj[key]);
  return new_obj;
}
```

See if this works. 
Here we created a pure function to copy the object, remove falsy keys and then return the new object.

Comment: Nice. Incidentally your function seems to work without `const new_obj = {...myObject};` (so long as you change 'myObject' to 'new_obj' in the 1st line of course).

Comment: In a pure function you should not do that. Our goal is to create a function that makes a copy of your object and does whatever it need to do there and return the new object. 

After this function if you console log both filter and the newly returned object you will see that your filter object is not changed. But the new returned object does not have any falsy value

But if you want to change your existing object only

Object.keys(new_obj).forEach(key=> new_obj[key] || new_obj[key]===0 ? new_obj[key] : delete new_obj[key]);

only this line was enough